# Need help getting immlib module to work

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, dll, dllimport, importerror

So I tried setting up the Immunity Debugger for Python but I am running into a lot of problems.

First I tried getting the immlib module through pip but as I soon found out that is not the way to get that module for Python.

So I installed the Immunity Debugger and could still not import immlib.
Then I came across the following post:

[How to install immlib module in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439189/how-to-install-immlib-module-in-python)

I tried all the following recommendations to install immlib but none seem to work.

It did seem to fix the part where Python would throw the import error of no module named immlib.

But then I got the following error when trying to import immlib:

"ImportError: No module named debugger"

So I went to the file location of the Immunity Debugger and found there was a file called "debugger.pyd".

Nothing I did seemed to work so I installed the debugger module through pip and now when trying to import immlib I get the following error:

"File "", line 1, in 
    debugger.EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT;
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT'"

So what am I doing wrong here? If possible could anyone please explain to me how to get the Immunity Debugger to work with Python?

I am running Python 2.7.9

---UPDATE---

Sometimes immlib will now import successfully but around 90% of trying to import the module it will throw the following error:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.`

Comment: I've no experience with this module, but you said you *did* try all of the recommendations on that link, including the `sys.path.append(<Immunity Debugger Path>..`?

Comment: I'm not sure which endpoints the path needs to see, but did you try just pointing to the directory in the first path, (exclude the `ImmunityDebugger.exe`)? I think that "no module named debugger" is trying to resolve to the `debugger.pyd` in the directory, so try just pointing to the directory

Comment: Sorry yes, I accidentally pasted the ImmunityDebugger.exe in my comment but I did the following using `sys.path.append`,
`sys.path.append('C:/Program Files (x86)/Immunity Inc/Immunity Debugger')`
`sys.path.append('C:/Program Files (x86)/Immunity Inc/Immunity Debugger/Libs')`

Comment: I uninstall the debugger module using pip and now receive the following error when trying to import immlib:

`import debugger
ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.`

This is probably now throwing an error on the debugger.pyd

Comment: ouch, hmm..i've no idea, i've read over [How to debug DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173944/how-to-debug-dll-load-failed-invalid-access-to-memory-location) but still no idea yet...

Comment: Perhaps the location you've installed it to, presumably `'C:/Program Files (x86)/..` doesn't have permissions for python? Maybe try installing the module to a different location? Perhaps like an empty directory on your desktop, `/Users/<user>/Desktop/`, or `Downloads", etc, something that has your users permissions, and doesn't require Administrator permissions.

Comment: I reinstalled the Immunity debugger into a folder on my desktop and am still receiving the `import debugger ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.` error.

Comment: Ok, sorry I haven't been of any help. Just to be sure, you also uninstalled the first installation (Immunity Debugger in "C:\Program Files", et. al.) and updated the `sys.path.append` paths to the Desktop location?

Comment: Yes I removed Immunity Debugger and then reinstalled it and also removed the old sys paths linking to its previous folder. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: What is your Windows Language set to? (non-English?) This is a far reach guess, but in searching I found other programs get this error on systems that users have their Windows non-English primary Language before installing. (Like [this thread in Can't start Calibre in Windows](http://www.mobileread.mobi/forums/showthread.php?s=a57739ce7f17a4c12695a36f335560c4&t=34546&page=2))

Comment: My Windows is set to English-US language format

Comment: So far all I can narrow the problem down to is something with `debugger.pyd` incorrectly loading the program's `.dll`s. A similar thread on [pyopencv](https://github.com/ewiger/pyopencv/issues/30) discusses inspecting the `.pyd` file with "Dependency Walker", but I've no experience with this.

Comment: I was able to fix it by reinstalling the debugger into my python folder for some strange reason it now doesn't throw any more errors and seems to work

Comment: It worked until I tried attaching to a process, now back at square one with the `import debugger ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I can't get it to run in Python itself I found a way of running the scripts through Immunity Debugger.

Using PyCommands it is possible to run the script and observe its behavior through the log console.
It might not be ideal but it does the job.

Thank you everyone for your effort and thought into this matter!